# CSS Brightness and Contrast Animation

Tags: css

I have a solid background that I want to alternate the brightness of on a loop using CSS on Chrome. The background will change to match a user's profile so it won't always be the same color.

As an example: The background could start out red, transition to a pinkish color and then back to red after a second.

Another example: The background could start out blue, transition to a baby blue color and then back to blue after a second.

I can accomplish the color effect by adjusting the brightness and contrast of the color but I don't know how to do this with webkit.

**How can I alternate the brightness and contrast using CSS and webkit?**

Comment: Why do you want to use brightness and contrast? Why not pick the pink color and the red one and alternate between those.

Comment: Why not make it in paint and then just use the resulting image as your background?

Comment: Because the color won't always be the same :(

Comment: If you animate the opacity, would that create the desired effect?

Comment: Possibly a minimal opacity might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: 
You can animate brightness and contrast the same way, but I'm not sure how you would like to achieve pink with that.

`Filters require the prefix -webkit-`

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {
        filter: brightness(1);
        filter: contrast(1);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
        -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
    }
    50%  {
        filter: brightness(0.4);
        filter: contrast(0.4);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(0.4);
        -webkit-filter: contrast(0.4);
    }
    100% {
        filter: brightness(1);
        filter: contrast(1);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
        -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81Lfz403/4/)**

Why use brightness and contrast when you can just tween between the colors?

```
div {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: pink;}
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81Lfz403/)**

Or if you want to loop it without the blink

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background: red;}
    50%  {background: pink;}
    100% {background: red;}
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81Lfz403/1/)**

Comment: This is not changing the brightness or contrast of the color just tweening between two colors.

Comment: @KenJ See my update. Though I'm curious how you want to achieve pink with those filters

Comment: Hint :-): As start and end has the same properties, you can save lines by writing `0%, 100% {...}`